# HEX value to its transparent color

Tags: c++, colors

I do know how to create HEX code of the color with given R, G, B values in C++. My code is:

```
#define COLOR_RGBA(%1,%2,%3,%4) (((((%1) & 0xff) << 24) | (((%2) & 0xff) << 16) | (((%3) & 0xff) << 8) | ((%4) & 0xff)))
```

This generates a color HEX 00FF005A (%90 transparency). Sometimes I don't have the R, G, B values of the color so there should be an other way. I tried:

```
the_hex_color | 00 & 0xff
```

but it didn't work and gave me the same output as I provided.

How can I find transparency HEX of the color without needing R, G, B values? Do I have to convert it back to it's R, G, B values?

Comment: Macro parameters must be identifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a full value and you want to extract only the part at 0xff then you need mask it out by doing:

```
the_hex_color & 0xff
```

What you were doing with the bitwise-or operator wasn't working because OR combines all the bits into the result.

---

EDIT - Now that I understand what's desired: To affect or zero out just the transparency byte.

Zeroing out a byte can be done as using AND with a mask to extract everything else:

```
color_transparent = original_color & 0xffffff00
```

Taking this a step further, if you want a way to update the color's transparency to a different value, then after the AND operation you could combine (OR) in the desired value:

```
updated_color = (original_color & 0xffffff00) | new_transparency_value
```

Comment: I did solve the problem with doing `original_color | 0x00000000`